# Python "prickle" package has no attribute "unpack"

Tags: python, python-3.x, unpack

I'm trying to use the prickle package: https://github.com/cswaney/prickle

I installed the package using the commands displayed in the README, but when I try to run the following code, I get this error: "AttributeError: module 'prickle' has no attribute 'unpack'". Additionally, I get the following error with the pk.read() command: "AttributeError: module 'prickle' has no attribute 'read'".

```py
import prickle as pk

pk.unpack(fin='itch_010113.bin',
          ver=4.1,
          date='2013-01-01',
          fout='itch.hdf5',
          nlevels=10,
          names=['GOOG', 'AAPL'],
          method='hdf5')
```

Can someone please let me know how to correct these errors?

Comment: What is the name of your script? Is it `prickle.py` by any chance?

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you!